# bad substitution running aws-cli for-loop

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, sh, aws-cli

I'm trying to run the below command but receiving a bad substitution error.

```
for i in ${aws eks list-clusters --query 'clusters' --output text | tr '\t' '\n' | grep dev-shark}; do aws eks describe-cluster --name $i | jq '.cluster.tags."Dev-Ver"'; done
```

see error msg below

```
bash: ${aws eks list-clusters --query 'clusters' --output text | tr '\t' '\n' | grep dev-shark}: bad substitution
```

Any ideas what maybe causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: You have curly braces around the pipeline -- `${aws ... dev-shark}` instead of parentheses. `${ }` is for variable substitution, `$( )` is for command substitution.

Comment: @GordonDavisson fantastic!!! This has resolved the issue! Thank you very much for your help. I'll make a note of this for future use. If you post this as the answer I can then accept it :)

Comment: It's probably better to just close the question as a typo, since that's basically all this was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't use `for` to read lines](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

I'd suggest pipe the output of the `aws|tr|grep` pipeline into a `while read` loop: adding line continuations and newlines for readability

```sh
aws eks list-clusters --query 'clusters' --output text \
| tr '\t' '\n' \
| grep dev-shark \
| while IFS= read -r line; do
      aws eks describe-cluster --name "$line" \
      | jq '.cluster.tags."Dev-Ver"'
  done
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion it worked first time :)

Answer (score 1):

The last pipe is not setting any action "| dev-shark", are you looking to filter against the text "dev-shark" then the code should be

```
for i in ${aws eks list-clusters --query 'clusters' --output text | tr '\t' '\n' | grep dev-shark}; do aws eks describe-cluster --name $i | jq '.cluster.tags."Dev-Ver"'; done
```

Comment: thank you for pointing this out. It was a case of cut & paste gone wrong. I have ammended the OP. The issue was resolved per GordonDavisson suggestion above concerning the $( ) command substitution.